# How to get editable text in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

How to get edited text message in MFMessageComposeViewController

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    // for appear message view
    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageVC = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    messageVC.body = messageString;
    messageVC.recipients = @[@"53645454", @"5445454545"];

    // prepare message view for send Message
    [self presentViewController:messageVC animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Can you describe more about your problem ?

Comment: @Wolverine: what ever message text we entered that text  i need to save.